# how to use config in flask extensions when use factory pattern in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I use factory pattern and flask extensions such as flask-admin during the development of web application. I want to load some configurations in flask-admin when the app haven't created. So i use the `current_app.config["SOME_CONFIG"]` to get the config value.But i got the `Working outside of application context.` exception. The code as follows:

```
# __init__.py

from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_name)
    app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")

    from admin import admin
    admin.init_app(app)

    return app


# admin/__init__.py

from flask import current_app
from flask_admin import Admin

admin = Admin(name=current_app.config["ADMIN_NAME"], template="bootstrap2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your application is still in the setup state during the create_app function (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/). During the setup state you need to have a reference to the application object to access it, you can't use current_app.

You could instantiate the Admin object within the create_app function using:

`admin = Admin(name=app.config["ADMIN_NAME"], template="bootstrap2")`

OR

change the admin variable and create a function in your `admin/__init__.py`:

```
admin = object()
def instantiate_admin(config):
    global admin
    admin = Admin(name=config["ADMIN_NAME"], template="bootstrap2")
    return admin
```

and use this in create_app():

```
from admin import instantiate_admin 
admin = instantiate_admin(app.config)
admin.init_app(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set it up like the following.

```
# config.py
class Config(object):
    ADMIN_NAME = 'admin'

# __init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin

# initiate all extensions here
admin = Admin(template='bootstrap2')

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)

    admin.init_app(app)
    return app

# wsgi.py
from . import create_app
from config import Config

app = create_app(Config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And in you admin package

```
# admin/__init__.py
from .. import admin # import extensions from __init__.py

admin.add_view('blah')
```

Below is a link to an real world example. I scrubbed info so it is more generic but this is how i setup all my flask apps.

http://hastebin.com/likupoxoxi.py

As long as you are running the dev server you shouldn't have issues that keeps it in the context of the application.